# How could mean function can directly calculate percentage rate?

Tags: r

[image]

this really confused me, how could a mean function calculate percentage rate rather than using count(vote==1) / total?

this is from DataCamp's The United Nations voting dataset

can someone explain this to me?

Comment: if you take `mean(vote==1)` you'll get a proportion since TRUE/FALSE values are converted to 1/0. Proportion is number true over total number. and number true is sum() and total number is length(). so `sum(x==TRUE)/length(x)` is just `mean(x==TRUE)` Make this can further clarify: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/07/proportions-with-mean/

Comment: Hi, I have checked the original dataset: votes, in the vote column, it indicates: <dbl>, how can it know that is a logical vector (1 for true, 0 for false)?

Comment: Vote may be double, but vote==1 will be logical. The data set would need to be documented to know exactly that the values in that column actually mean.